What is the difference between 'loadSPFX=true' vs 'debug=true' query string parameter in debugging SPFx webpart
In SharePoint documentation (Link), it is specified to use the below query string for debugging the webpart in a page,
?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js

But spfx-serve mention to use the below one to debug webpart in page,
?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js


I am just wondering about the difference b/w these two.!!
Related: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6288

It might depend on a version (older vs newer).
loadSPFX=true was necessary in earlier SPFx versions to ensure that the SPFx framework was loaded. However, in current versions, debug=true is used to enable debugging features, making loadSPFX=true somewhat obsolete.
